# Identifying Nullable vs Non Nullable fields in an Object

Tags: metadata-api, required-field

I am using Salesforce Metadata API and facing an issue with identifying fields that are nullable. The nillable parameter doesn't seem to be 100% accurate.

For example, in the Order object, the AccountId field ( Lookup to an Account record) is Nillable (nillable: true). But if I try to insert an Order without AccountId, Salesforce complains

[image]

How can someone programmatically identify that this is a required lookup?

Same issue exists for the ContractId field of the Orders object.

Comment: By programmatically, do you mean in Apex?

Comment: `Order.AccountID` is required in schema, `Order.ContractId` is not; both are defined as nillable in the doc and via describe -- I think you've found one of the handful of exceptions where describe doesn't agree with implementation reality

Comment: @cropredy, agreed. Would you know of a way to find all of these inconsistencies?

Comment: @VictorLockwood, we are using Metadata API at the moment and are hoping to use the same.   If you know of another Salesforce API family that could help us identify this, that would be great as well.

Comment: I do not -- this is more a question for the platform product managers so you might try one of the social media platforms monitored by SFDC product managers

Comment: @cropredy, I raised a question in the trailhead community. No responses yet there. I am fairly new to Salesforce. If you have any recommendations on the platforms/groups that the SFDC PMs monitor, I'd appreciate it.